# count rows in longest sharepoint list javascript

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, javascript, custom-list, jsom

I want to get count rows in a List some have longest name while I am looping through all Lists. I want it in JavaScript

Answer (score 3):

Use below script to list all Lists and its Item Count

```
var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
var lists = context.get_web().get_lists();

context.load(lists, "Include(Title, ItemCount)");
context.executeQueryAsync(success, fail);

function success() {
    var maxLength = 0;
    var longestTitle = '';
    var itemCount = 0;
    var enumerator = lists.getEnumerator();
    while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
        var list = enumerator.get_current();
        if(maxLength < list.get_title().length) {
             maxLength = list.get_title().length;
             longestTitle = list.get_title(); 
             itemCount = list.get_itemCount();
        }
    }
    alert(longestTitle);
    alert(itemCount);
}
```

Comment: this is my code i use to get the longest listname in my siteCollection                              `code` var listEnumerator = listCollection.getEnumerator();
    while (listEnumerator.moveNext()) {
        var currentItem = listEnumerator.get_current(),
            title = currentItem.get_title();


        listString += "<br>" + title;

        if (longest.length < title.length)
            longest = title;
    } `code`

Comment: I have updated my answer

Comment: thnxxx for ur help :)